# Find serial number of Samsung Galaxy S7 edge

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

How can I find out the serial number of a Samsung Galaxy S7 edge without the sticker on the phone / box?

I've tried a few 'secret codes', but nothing happens when I type them in:
http://geekofreak.com/2013/01/all-secret-codes-of-samsung-mobile-phone.html

I've tried downloading Kies on my computer, but it says my phone is unsupported and I need to download SmartSwitch. I've installed SmartSwitch on the phone but it doesn't seem to be for verifying the phone.

Comment: Isn't it in Settings - About Phone - Status like every other Android device?

Comment: No for me it isnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try using [Phone Info Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo). It is a very versatile app and gives you a lot of information on Samsung devices (many may come as a surprise). I have used it for four years on my previous devices. Developer has an [active thread at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=49394347)

Play store  snapshot claims that it displays serial number too. It did that on my old Note 2

[image]