# Find out model code for Samsun Galaxy 7 edge?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

Under "About device" I can see my model number is SM-G935F. However when I try and register my phone with Samsung it needs the "Model code/name" eg "SM-G935FZDABTU Galaxy S7 edge United Kingdom".

How can I find this extra information?

Comment: [under the battery](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/generic/samsung-galaxy-s7).

Comment: Which is not removable...

Comment: lol under the battery, are you serious?

Comment: @esQmo:: Heh.. Samsung says so.. I clean forgot that this didn't have recoverable battery, like Note 2 which had removable battery, my last Samsung device. Added other options in solution below

Comment: @beeshyams +1 for that. ;)

Comment: may be the bot is sleeping somewhere :D

Comment: Related: [Find serial number of Samsung Galaxy S7 edge](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/160684/16575). Same solution might apply here (I'd wonder if that app @beeshyams mentions there wouldn't cover this one, too).

Comment: @Izzy:: It does, but the developer of the app himself mentions that the database may be inaccurate and suggests an alternate method, which is the last bullet point in the answer // Hint to OP- reason of mentioning developer XDA thread in previous answer, was to get  quick answers to Samsung *device* related stuff

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @beeshyams No I havnt.

Comment: Will search and post if I can find. Download mode didn't reveal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- see the long list of model codes for your device [here](https://www.techwalls.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge-model-numbers-differences/).  (Since you didn't mention your country)
- [OEM](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/generic/samsung-galaxy-s7) says for S7, it is under the battery, so that's likely where you could find, but as mentioned by you , it's not removable
- > Reboot the phone into the Download Mode (a.k.a Odin Mode) to see the Model.

( From the [developer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=62351837#post62351837) of Phone info Samsung mentioned in [earlier question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/160684/131553) )