# Is there a way to know if the installed Android is official?

Tags: stock-android, stock-rom, motorola-moto-g2

I know that if one has access to the firmware files, one can check if the firmware is the official stock firmware or not by looking at the SHA1.

Now, suppose that Android has already been installed on the device. Is there a way to check whether or not the installed Android is the official stock version or not?

Maybe there's some information that can be found in another identical device running the same Android version that can be compared?

Comment: My device is one Motorola Moto G 2014 XT1069. I didn't specify because I thought that there was a general method.

Comment: @beeshyams The question was tagged `motorola-moto-g2` and I assumed that was correct, thus my Motorola specific answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the bootloader screen, there is a field that says Software Status, if it says "Official", well, then it's official.

You can access the bootloader screen by powering off, then hold Vol Dn and Power until together until the screen appears.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @acejavelin. Are you sure this works for Moto G XT1069? I accessed the bootloader screen but I found no field "Software Status" there. Is this for some specific version of Android?

Comment: Does it not look like this: http://imgur.com/a/fK5Rk

Comment: @user1620696 Hmm... it seems the 1st and 2nd Gen G's use a different bootloader screen layout. Look at the Status Code, if it is 0 or 2 and the bootloader is locked, it is Official. If it is unlocked or a different code then there is no way to be sure and reflashing the stock image would be recommended if you doubt it's authenticity. In theory if the bootloader is locked on Moto devices, it must be official software, it should not be locked or relockable unless the software digitally signed.

Answer (score 1):

To add other methods

- Samsung phones have an [app](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160685/131553) that can check. Possibly other brands may also be having similar apps
- If the device OS is Lollipop and above and it accepts OTA , it is offical since it has passed  *block based OTA* as explained here [How do I verify my firmware is legitimate?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159797/131553).
- One can also check by using the *update app* of your device. If it returns "update available" , I suppose it verified the existing firmware

Solution of acejavelin is perhaps the easiest

Answer (score 0):

Try the checkey app in the play store think it maybe exactly what your looking for.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to add a link to the app you're recommending, and explain why you're recommending it? That would be a lot more helpful.